# How to refresh the value of JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```java
if(e.getSource()== submit){
    // Error Handling
    if(viewSelection.getText().equals("Empty") || textField.getText().isBlank()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong Value");
    }else {
        try {
            dataFile.EditData(viewSelection.getText(), dataFile.ReadData(), Integer.parseInt(textField.getText()));
            // table.setValueAt(dataFile.material.get(viewSelection.getText()), 0,0);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved Data!");

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
String header[] = {"material", "stack"};
String contents[][] = {
        {milk.getText(), dataFile.material.get(milk.getText())},
        {vanila.getText(), dataFile.material.get(vanila.getText())},
        {coffeebean1.getText(), dataFile.material.get(coffeebean1.getText())},
        {coffeebean2.getText(), dataFile.material.get(coffeebean2.getText())},
        {coffeebean3.getText(), dataFile.material.get(coffeebean3.getText())},
        {choco.getText(), dataFile.material.get(choco.getText())},
        {caramel.getText(), dataFile.material.get(caramel.getText())},
        {icecream.getText(), dataFile.material.get(icecream.getText())},
        {sweatMilk.getText(), dataFile.material.get(sweatMilk.getText())}
};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(contents, header);
table = new JTable(contents, header);
model.fireTableDataChanged();
JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

I was drawing up a program to import values from DataFile Class and change values through GUI.

I want to refresh the value of the `JTable` when user presses the submit button.

I've tried to change the column value of the table, but I'm worried because it didn't work....

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data, for the first **two** data rows (all that's needed). 2) As to the crux of the question, **to update the table, add data to the table mode.** It really is that simple. See [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to me that you have to execute all this code again, each time the user presses the submit button:

```java
String header[] = {"material", "stack"};
String contents[][] = {
        {milk.getText(), dataFile.material.get(milk.getText())},
        {vanila.getText(), dataFile.material.get(vanila.getText())},
        {coffeebean1.getText(), dataFile.material.get(coffeebean1.getText())},
        {coffeebean2.getText(), dataFile.material.get(coffeebean2.getText())},
        {coffeebean3.getText(), dataFile.material.get(coffeebean3.getText())},
        {choco.getText(), dataFile.material.get(choco.getText())},
        {caramel.getText(), dataFile.material.get(caramel.getText())},
        {icecream.getText(), dataFile.material.get(icecream.getText())},
        {sweatMilk.getText(), dataFile.material.get(sweatMilk.getText())}
};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(contents, header);
table = new JTable(contents, header);
```

It's the same than your's. It seems that this is the code that you use to display the values from DataFile in the table, so you can put this code in a function and call the function at the start of the program and each time the submit button is pressed